# WSGI content encoding

Tags: python, http, utf-8, character-encoding, content-type

If I execute the following Python 3.1 program, I see only � instead of the correct characters in my browser. The file itself is UTF-8 encoded and the same encoding is sent with the response.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

page = "<html><body>äöü€ßÄÖÜ</body></html>"

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response("200 Ok", [("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")])
    return page

httpd = make_server('', 8000, application)
print("Serving on port 8000...")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

"UTF-8" is set correctly in the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Ok
Date: Mon, 09 Aug 2010 16:35:02 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/3.1.1+
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WSGI on Python 3 doesn't exist yet. The Web-SIG have still not reached any conclusion about how strings (bytes/unicode) are to be handled in Python 3.x.

`wsgiref` is largely an automated 2to3 conversion; it still has problems even apart from the factor of what WSGI on 3.x will actually mean. Don't rely on it as a reference to how WSGI apps will work under Python 3.

That the situation is *still* like this coming into the 3.2 release cycle is embarrassing and depressing.

```
return page
```

Well, whilst WSGI for 3.x is still an unknown factor, one thing most agree on is that the response body of a WSGI app should generally be bytes and not unicode, since HTTP is a bytes-based protocol. Whether Unicode strings will be accepted—and if so what encoding they'll be converted with—remains to be seen, so avoid the issue and return bytes:

```
return [page.encode('utf-8')]
```

(The `[]` are needed because WSGI apps should return an iterable that's output and flushed an item at a time. If you pass a string on its own, that's used as an iterable and returned a character at a time, which is horrible for performance.)

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. But `return page.encode('utf-8')` doesn't work. I get the following error from the WSGI runtime: `AssertionError: write() argument must be a string or bytes`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited the bit about `[]` in afterwards! The case where `[]` is missing fails harder for byte strings than for unicode because in Python 3, `b'A'[0]` is the integer 65, not `b'A'`. Pretty much the worst mistake Python 3 made, IMO.

Comment: I wouldn't say its a mystake. It makes sense that b"A" represent a byte and not a char. That way it's almost impossible to mixup str and unicode like before.

Comment: I had the same thing with Python 3.5.  I don't know if anything changed but until I did the page.encode in the return, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are not `UTF-8`; they are `latin-1`. If you put those literals into your Python source code (which you shouldn't do), you need to declare the encoding of the file, by placing the following line at the top:

```
#-*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

and serving in `latin-1`:

```
start_response("200 Ok", [("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=latin-1")])
```

Assuming you meant to do everything in UTF-8, you need to look up the code points for those characters. You can then do

```
page = u"\x--\x--...\x--"
```

and serve that up as Unicode.

Note that you can verify this by changing the encoding of your browser; if you manually change it to `latin-1` the characters will display fine.

Comment: I thought that `#-*- coding: ...` is not needed with Python >= 3. The characters shown could in principal be written with UTF-8 directly.